# Hapi server methods vs server.app.doSomething

Tags: hapi.js

I am writing a hapi js plugin, and was wondering what's the difference between the two ways of exposing methods that other plugins can use.

Method 1:

```
server.method("doSomething",
    function () {
        // Something
    });
```

Method 2:

```
server.app.doSomething = function () {
    // Something
};
```

In the first approach, the function can later be called as server.doSomething(), while using the second approach as server.app.doSomething().

So why would I use one way instead of another?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the API docs it sounds like they intended `server.methods` to be used for functions and `server.app` to be used for app settings/configuration. My guess is you should stick with server.method if you want to expose server level methods to be used in your plugins.

> #### server.methods
>
> An object providing access to the server methods where each server
>   method name is an object property.
>
> ```
> var Hapi = require('hapi');
> var server = new Hapi.Server();
>
> server.method('add', function (a, b, next) {
>
>     return next(null, a + b);
> });
>
> server.methods.add(1, 2, function (err, result) {
>
>     // result === 3
> });
> ```
>
> #### server.app
>
> Provides a safe place to store server-specific run-time application
>   data without potential conflicts with the framework internals. The
>   data can be accessed whenever the server is accessible. Initialized
>   with an empty object.
>
> ```
> var Hapi = require('hapi');
> server = new Hapi.Server();
> server.app.key = 'value';
>
> var handler = function (request, reply) {
>
>     return reply(request.server.app.key);
> };
> ```

Comment: Although it doesn't really answer, why would I use one against the other, in terms of functionality, but I accept this as a "matter of convention" I guess...

Comment: Perhaps different scoping to other Hapi servers running in the same app? I've been wondering the same as the op for a while and this is the best answer I've seen yet despite not really answering the "why one vs the other" question :)